# Exporting eclipse-rcp help files as standalone html pages

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Eclipse-RCP provides some facilies (plugins org.eclipse.help.ui , org.eclipse.help.webapp ) to add Help to an application. It mostly consists of plain HTML pages, together with some xml files to provide the content structure (TOCS). At runtime, eclipse adds some javascript+css magic to generate the index+navigation menu in a left frame, insert breadcrumbs, etc.

Is there some way to get some dump of these decorated pages, so that I can put them in a (static) web server? I can only think of capture them with a website **scraper** , but it doesnt seem very straighforward, I wonder if there is some easier way.

UPDATE: I ended using the Eclipse web server: I exported a trimmed version of my (Windows) Eclipse-RCP application (not very easy to know which plugins are needed) to my linux server, and added to the startup scripts a new script that invokes the `org.eclipse.help.standalone.Help` class:

```
java -classpath plugins/org.eclipse.help.base_3.5.2.v201009090800.jar org.eclipse.help.standalone.Help -command start -port 55555 -noexec -eclipsehome $EDIR
```

Afterwards, I setup a reverse proxy in my Apache server to hit the Eclipse server. It worked quited well. I don't add this as answer because it doesn't follow my initial requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the Eclipse RCP application is the Eclipse plug-in that contains the plan HTML Help pages and the TOCS xml files that you're interested in.

Unzip the Eclipse plug-in, and copy the HTML files to your web server.

You'll have to provide the navigation that org.eclipse.help.ui provides with the TOCS xml files.

Comment: I have the plain HTML files, what I lack is the "decoration" that eclipse plugins adds to it (breadcrumbs, navigation menu).